# Transform a xml into java object using mule 4.3 kernal (CE)

Tags: transform, message, dataweave, mule4, mule-esb

We can transform a xml payload into java object by mapping elements using Transform Message component in Mule 4.3 EE.
Can we transform a xml into java object using mule 4.3 kernal (CE) instead of using EE ?

Answer (score 1):

The actual XML element in the flow for Transform Message is `<ee:transform>`. The `ee` namespace indicates it is an Enterprise Edition (EE) feature. So the answer would be that you can not use Transform Message in Mule Kernel, also known as Mule Community Edition (CE).